# warning: cannot close "core.xxxxx": Invalid operation

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, gdb, coredump

Let's say i attach to process 5400 using `gdb.exe -pid 5400`. When i try to save core dump using `gcore` or `gcore nameoffile` into file, i'm getting an error that says `warning: cannot close "core.5400": Invalid operation` in cmd. I tried different versions and tried to attach to other programs but same error.

My PC is running Windows 10 x64. I'm using pre-build gdb for Windows http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=gdb

Comment: The source code appears to be [here](https://bitbucket.org/staceyoi/bb101repo/src/cd731c4615fd5b9e806e6bdc9ffa3ea7b9c95826/Src/gnu/gdb/corelow.c?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#corelow.c-269). I suspected that lack of enough space or lack of write permission caused the `bfd_close` to fail. None of them were correct (based on 2501).

Comment: In my case the file gets created, but it's empty. Attaching to and debugging the process otherwise works correctly.

Comment: did you check core file size limit? May be it was set to 0 in your case.

Comment: @Srini How do you do that in Windows?

Comment: Looks like `gcore` is not implemented for gdb on Windows.